# How to design an impedance meter?

Tags: circuit-design, impedance, passive-networks

I am designing an impedance meter with NI devices. I am applying 0-20 uA current signal to an RC circuit and measuring the voltage. Impedance is calculated by dividing Vp-p by Ip-p. I am controlling NI devices (both current output and voltage input) through MATLAB. Setup is displayed below.

[image]

I am getting these results:
[image]
My questions:

1. Why voltage signal is negative?
2. Impedance doesn't change when I change frequency of the current signal. Why?
3. When I change the amplitude of the current signal, impedance changes. Why?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The impedance of a two terminal circuit is defined as the voltage across the terminals divided by the current into one terminal (which presumably exits the other terminal).  In your schematic you show a current into the circuit but the voltage is at the output of the circuit rather than the input. You also haven't described your circuit so I don't know what the output voltage even means.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have updated the setup diagram. Do you think its not the right setup?

Comment: The setup looks OK. But the impedance should definitely change with frequency. You haven't given the values of the components.  It's possible that the reactance of the capacitors is much higher than the resistance of the resistors so it does not have much of an effect on the overall impedance. If the impedance you calculate depends on the current level, then something is wrong with your setup.  I suggest you start off with just a resistor and check if your setup comes up with the correct resistance.  Then try just a capacitor.  If they work, then you can keep adding components.

Comment: I have updated the figure with component values. I have also checked with just resistor and capacitor. Certain frequencies give better results in finding the impedance of the resistance alone (voltage signal is still negative).  Voltage is positive while finding impedance of capacitor alone however, impedance and current signal amplitude has an effect on impedance. Impedance values are different than a commercially available LCR meter.

Answer (score 0):

This case needs some guessing. There's two main possiblities

1. Your circuit has much longer time constant than your pulse length. The changes in the measured voltage are caused mainly by the current in Rs, the capacitor voltages do not change visibly in 50ms. The capacitors have some preloaded voltage which do not get discharged in one second through the resistors.
2. Your circuit has very short time constant, maybe 1ms or less. In addition you have error somewhere, the measured voltage has constant DC offset which causes the voltage is not zero when the current is zero.

The truth and the reasons for the precharging or offset error are impossible to see without knowing the values of the components and without any knowledge of your actual measuring interface. NI has a wide repertoire of stuff. Letters N and I do not tell the models nor how you have connected them.

Your impedance concept is quite different than the normally used altough surely no crime laws have been broken. With resistors the concept should give the same results than the ordinary one. Try at first one resistor to reveal major errors.

Simulating your circuit gives the following behaviour:

[image]

[image]

That's different than your measured behaviour. I believe you measure a wrong voltage or a right voltage in a wrong way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have updated the figure with component values. I have also checked with just resistor and capacitor. Certain frequencies give better results in finding the impedance of the resistance alone (voltage signal is still negative).  Voltage is positive while finding impedance of capacitor alone however, impedance and current signal amplitude has an effect on impedance. Impedance values are different than a commercially available LCR meter.